# Why does each Doctor change out of his predecessor's clothes immediately after regenerating?

Tags: doctor-who

When a Doctor has just regenerated, he is wearing the clothes of his predecessor.

- 9th to 10th

  [image: David Tennant as the Doctor in all black clothes and a long black leather coat walking down the street with his arms out strecthed]
- 10th to 11th

  [image: Matt Smith as the Doctor inside the Tardis in his traditional tweed suit]
- 11th to 12th

  [image: Peter Capaldi as the Doctor in his tweed old fashioned suit outside looking up at the sky]

Then they pass out  immediately, then change into different clothes, which I didn't like. Why does each Doctor change out of his predecessor's clothes immediately after regenerating? Why can't they be in their predecessor's clothes longer for a while?

Comment: How well do you like wearing other people's clothes that don't fit properly?

Comment: from these pictures it looks like they fit

Comment: Not to me. In the first one, they're too big, and in the second they're too small. Besides, they're still someone else's clothes.

Comment: i just wanted to see them  be in their predecessor's clothes longer for a while

Comment: "It looks like they fit" - Are you kidding? 10th doctor is swimming in 9th doctor's clothes, and both the 11th and 12th doctors barely fit in their previous incarnation's clothing.

Comment: how they look fine swimming really and 11 and 12 look like they fit good

Comment: To be fair, Whittaker in Capaldi's clothes was amusing. For about 30 seconds...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there's a single reason, it's this:

### In general, it's because tastes are a function of personality

The Doctor dresses to suit *himself*, and nobody else; his clothes are chosen (by him) to reflect his new personality. Since his personality (self-evidently) changes with regeneration, so too does his style.

Nowhere is this more evident than in the Sixth Doctor's debut episode, where he explicitly rejects several staples of prior wardrobes:

> (The Doctor has recovered from his momentary breakdown and is looking through various outfits. He picks out [Patrick Troughton's fur coat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsXMz.jpg).)
>
> **Doctor:** Hmm? No.
>
> (He throws it down and picks up a [red velvet jacket a la Jon Pertwee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srvTk.jpg).)
>
> **Peri:** Are you sure you're all right?
>
> **Doctor:** My dear child, stop worrying. Try to understand. Regeneration in my case is a swift but volcanic experience. A kind of violent biological eruption in which the body cells are displaced, changed, renewed and rearranged.
>
> (He tries on the jacket then discards it.)
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* Season 21 Episode 7: "The Twin Dilemma"</sup>

Or a similar montage early in the Seventh Doctor's debut episode, where he does much the same thing:

> (The traditional post-regeneration scene. First up, [a Napoleon costume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP7IR.jpg).)
>
> **Doctor:** No, I think not. Lacks my natural humility.
>
> (He tries on a Bearskin hat.)
>
> **Doctor:** Doesn't look right without a horse. I need something more dignified, Timelord-ish.
>
> ([A school master's mortar board and gown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe02S.jpg).)
>
> **Doctor:** A little portentous, perhaps, Mel?
>
> **Rani:** Pretentious is the word.
>
> ([Tom Baker's burgundy coat, hat and scarf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoWxk.jpg).)
>
> **Doctor:** Old hat?
>
> ([Jon Pertwee's frilly shirt and velvet jacket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geaJo.jpg).)
>
> **Doctor:** Not frilled.
>
> ([Peter Davison's cricketing gear, with bat and pads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc7hB.jpg).)
>
> **Doctor:** How's that? Would that bowl a maiden over?
>
> ([Patrick Troughton's fur coat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNmik.jpg). He flings it open to reveal a question mark motif pullover and red braces under a cream linen jacket. He has kept the panama hat.)
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* Season 24 Episode 1: "Time and the Rani"</sup>

We can also look to a comment made by the Twelfth Doctor in "Deep Breath":

> **Doctor:** I need um, I need clothes. I need clothes, that's what I need. And a big, long scarf. No, no, move on from that. Looked stupid.
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* Series 8 Episode 1: "Deep Breath"</sup>

However, I might point out that it's not always so clear-cut:

### Sometimes he doesn't have a choice

All three of your examples are ones where the Doctor is forced out of his clothes by circumstances beyond his control:

- The Tenth Doctor loses consciousness almost immediately upon landing in London, and is next seen in pyjamas and a dressing gown (belonging to Jackie's boyfriend); given his state, it's likely that Rose changed him so he'd be comfortable
- The Eleventh Doctor's clothes are ruined by his explosive regeneration, and the damage it causes to the TARDIS. He almost certainly would have changed sooner, if not for the *many* extenuating circumstances in the episode
- The Twelfth Doctor is incoherent and only occasionally-concsious. He was almost certainly undressed (and redressed in a nightshirt) by one of his caretakers

This is true of other incarnations as well:

- The Third Doctor loses consciousness in a field, and wakes up wearing a hospital gown; presumably he was changed by a nurse
- Similarly, the Eighth Doctor wakes up in a morgue, having been declared dead before his regeneration. His clothes would have been removed by hospital staff, likely in preparation for an autopsy

### He doesn't *always* change much, or change immediately

- It's worth noting that the costume change between the First and Second Doctors is quite minimal:

  [image: The First Docotr wearing a monocle, waistcoat, dinner jacket and kilt] [image: The Second Doctor in a similar outfit minus the monocle and with a different pattern on the kilt and no waistcoat]

  He abandons the waistcoat and monocle, and changes the tie, but otherwise remains very similar.
- As well, the Seventh Doctor runs around in his old clothes for pretty much an entire episode, much as some of us (myself included) wished he'd just abandon the damned coat already:

  [image: The Seventh Doctor in waistcoat and dinner jacket but in crazy vibrant colours]
- As I hinted above, the Eleventh Doctor spends the better part of his debut episode in the tattered remnants of the Tenth Doctor's wardrobe; note, for example, the tie he wears in the scene below (moments after resolving the main conflict of the episode):

  [image: The Eleventh Doctor in a hospital ward surrounded by patients on beds with a striped shirt and trousers on and a black tie with a swirling pattern]

  And compare to what David Tennant was wearing moments before his regeneration:

  [image: The Tenth Doctor in the Tardis looking at his glowing hand as he starts to regenerate, he is wearing the black tie with the swirling pattern on it that the next Doctor keeps for a while]

Comment: so why does the doctor dosent stay in his predecessor's cloths for longer

Comment: @AndrewCasali Because sometimes *other people* change his clothes for him, something he *does* stay in his predecessor's clothes, and most of the time he just doesn't *like* them anymore

Comment: which doctor should of stay inhis predecessor's cloths for longer

Comment: @AndrewCasali That's a matter I have no opinion on. Though I wish the Seventh Doctor had changed clothes *faster*. God I hated that outfit

Comment: what do you mean he dosent have a choice

Comment: @AndrewCasali I mean that his clothes are removed by other people while he is unconscious, or else destroyed by fire. Have you read my answer? It's all in there

Comment: does  the  The Eleventh Doctor's clothes are basically disintegrated by the damage his regeneration causes to the TARDIS explain why in the eleventh hour he only had the tie and blue shirt

Comment: @AndrewCasali That is the implication, yes.

Comment: i always wonderd in the eleventh hour why  he dint have the full suit from his last face 10th doctor and just the blue shirt and tie was it when he was hanging from the tardis  did he take the brown coat off then it fell out of the tardis

Comment: I quite liked that coat.

Comment: Come on, doesn't the Fourth Doctor get a mention [for this little charade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rH2QIAkyfCQ)? :-)

Comment: @ATB It's okay, I won't hold that against you

Comment: @Randal'Thor Sacrifices must be made, and I really do think the Sixth Doctor makes a better example; he explicitly rejects several of his own previous styles

Comment: Colin Baker complained vociferously about his wardrobe during interviews prior to the 50th anniversary special, complaining that the outfit he asked for was what they gave Christopher Eccleston.

Answer (score 2):

Every Doctor has a new face and a new distinct personality, the new clothes are the expression of the new personality.  Every Doctor has a unique 'look' and new accessories i.e. the recorder, the fedora and scarf, the leather jacket, the long trench coat, the fez and bow tie etc.

Comment: how does this explain why the doctor dosent stay in his predecessor's cloths for longer

Comment: Basically it's a new man - how would you like to wear someone else's underpants?